# Duda sobre repositorios en Github

Tags: github, terminal

Lo que pasa es que al subir el repositorio a github a través de la terminal a la hora de ingresar en la web al repositorio aparece mi nombre dos veces, le he cambiado con el siguiente comando:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Mr. Goding"
```

si se refleja el cambio pero aparece dos veces como se ve en la imagen, y en los repositorios de otros colegas sale solamente una vez su nombre, que es lo que tengo que hacer para que me aparezca una vez? se los agradecería [image: Al principio aparecia mi nombre completo y despues mi nombre de usuario]

Answer (score 1):

intenta con:

```
#obtener todos los nombres usuarios es key sensitive
git config --get-all user.name

#obtener el archivo de configuracion de los nombres de usuarios
git config -e
# y eliminas los que no quieres
```

o

```
#eliminar todos los nombres de usuarios
git config --global --unset-all user.name

#volver a configurar un usuario
git config --global user.name "Mr. Goding"
```

o

```
#remplazar todos los nombre de usuarios con una especifico 
git config --global --replace-all user.name "Mr. Goding"
```

Comment: Y todas esas sentencias para que sirven?

Comment: Mejora tu respuesta y explícala pues la dices que pruebe con tres opciones

Comment: Sigue apareciendo dos veces mi nombre de usuario, intenté con los comandos que insertaste y sale igual.